# Outlook Project: Ideas in automating a task checklist (based on macro enabled excel sheet) which I have to perform in a work shift

Tags: c#, excel, outlook, vba

Suppose, I have 3 tasks to be completed in a day.
I have these tasks written in an excel sheet which contains checkboxes. Once I complete  task 1, I go to excel sheet and click the checkbox in front of task 1.

**Problem**: I want to automate this process. So that when I complete task 1, the checklist automatically gets updated.

**Background**: I get emails in Microsoft Outlook 2010/2013 which assign me tasks (these are fixed tasks; constant 'subject line'). When task 1 is completed, I reply on the email stating it is completed.

**My idea on How**: Form bridge between Microsoft Outlook and macro enabled Excel sheet to automate it.

Your ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You are free to automate Excel from any Office applocation (Outlook in your case). The following articles describes the required actions in depth:

- [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C#.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084)
- [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/219151)

You just need to decide what kind of application you need to develop - an add-in or just a VBA macro code. If you need to distribute it on multiple PCs - the add-in is the right way to go. VBA macros are not designed for distributing.